# Why do i keep getting this error message?

Tags: python, oop

Hi i get this error: name 'passwords' is not defined when im about to check passwords that i have saved. Why do i get the error?

```
def login_or_register(self):

    user_input = input("Login or Register: ")

    if user_input == "login":
        self.login2()
    elif user_input == "register":
        pass
    else:
        print("Try again!")
        self.login_or_register()


def add_password(self):

    global sitepassword
    global site
    Site = input("Enter site name: ")
    sitepassword = input("Enter password")
    self.add_password_orCheck_password()

    global passwords
    self.passwords = {Site: sitepassword}

def check_passwords(self):
    which_password = input("Which sites password do you want to see?")
    for Site in passwords:
        if which_password in passwords:
            print(sitepassword)
            self.add_password_orCheck_password()




def add_password_orCheck_password(self):
    add_new = input("Do you want to add a password or check passwords?")
    if "add a password" in add_new:
        self.add_password()
    elif "check passwords" in add_new:
        self.check_passwords()



Matt = User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", "21.12.1999" ,"male", "Password987")
session1 = Matt.login_or_register()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `check_passwords`, the passwords variable is still local. Yes, you declared it global in another, but you also need to declare it in each function that uses the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `check_passwords` the variable is local still, so you need to use `global passwords` in each method before referring to the variable.